# Translate “algebra structure on” in mathematics

Tags: traduction, mathématiques

I want to translate this sentence in French.

> We study the Hopf algebra structure on the vector space spanned by [something]

In fact, this is what I tried.

> Nous présentons une structure d’algèbre de Hopf sur l’espace vectoriel engendré par les [quelques choses].

Who can correct me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good job you did. Your attempt is (almost) successful.

May be three short notes may be added though:

1. We translate ***the*** by ***la*** instead of ***une*** which is rather equivalent to ***a***.
2. We rather use ***dans*** to translate ***on*** (even if the translation of this proposition ***on*** is right, but for the sake of meaning of the sentence we use ***dans*** in this context)
3. Depending on the context, we may  better translated *We study* by:

   - *Nous **étudions**  **la** structure d’algèbre de Hopf **dans** l’espace vectoriel engendré par...*
   - *Nous **analysons**  **la** structure d’algèbre de Hopf **dans** l’espace vectoriel engendré par...*
   - *Nous présentons  **la** structure d’algèbre de Hopf **dans** l’espace vectoriel engendré par...*

Comment: I'd rather say *sur* or *de*, though.

Answer (score 6):

On dit bien "structure d'algèbre **sur** un espace vectoriel". Intuitivement, on a un espace vectoriel et on vient rajouter par-dessus une structure d'algèbre pour en faire une algèbre.

N'importe quel livre classique d'algèbre en français (par exemple le livre *Théorie des ensembles* de Bourbaki, on peut trouver "structure d'algèbre sur K" page IV.9) peut le confirmer (certaines personnes peuvent peut-être le lire [ici](https://books.google.fr/books?id=VDGifaOQogcC&pg=SL265-PA9&lpg=SL265-PA9&dq=%22structure+d%27alg%C3%A8bre+sur%22&source=bl&ots=C-8NtsLlgv&sig=Hua_PqD2vgrt7zGZJ2ICJwXfuNY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjm7mjueDKAhVCuhoKHVCUAp8Q6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=%22structure%20d'alg%C3%A8bre%20sur%22&f=false), même si Google Books ne donne pas accès aux mêmes livres à tout le monde).

On peut également comparer les recherches Google pour "structure d'algèbre sur" (937 résultats) et "structure d'algèbre dans" (5 résultats, du type "structure d'algèbre dans un cadre très général" ou "structure d'algèbre dans un premier temps" qui sont des faux-positifs). Les mêmes recherches sur Google scholar donnent respectivement [94 résultats](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&q=%22structure+d%27alg%C3%A8bre+sur%22&btnG=&lr=) et [4 résultats (dont un en anglais, bizarrement)](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=%22structure+d%27alg%C3%A8bre+dans%22&btnG=&hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5).

Le texte en anglais parle bien, par contre, de **la** structure d'algèbre de Hopf sur l'espace engendré par les [qqch]. La distinction entre "une" et "la" est importante en mathématiques.

---

One says "une structure d'algèbre **sur** un espace vectoriel". See e.g. Bourbaki, *Théorie des ensembles*, page IV.9 (or really, any classical book on algebra). However, one would say in your situation "**la** structure d'algèbre de Hopf sur [...]", because the distinction between "la/the" and "un/a" is important in mathematics.